# Validation in Modelviewset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have to validate image. I have tried add validator to field in `models.py`, but python cannot `migrate` validator depending on class. How can I add validation in this case in `views.py`

validators.py

```
class ValidateImageSize:
    MEASURE_UNIT_BYTE_MAP = {
        'kb': 1024,
        'mb': 1024 * 1024,
    }
    MEASURE_UNIT_NAME_MAP = {
        'kb': 'kilobyte',
        'mb': 'megabyte',
    }

    def __init__(self, max_size):
        max_size, measure_unit = max_size.split(' ')
        self.max_size = int(max_size)
        self.measure_unit = measure_unit

    def __call__(self, value):
        if value.size > self.max_size * self.MEASURE_UNIT_BYTE_MAP[self.measure_unit]:
            raise ValidationError(f'Size maximum is {self.max_size} {self.measure_unit}')
```

views.py

```
class EpisodeView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def create(self, request, story_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            story = Story.objects.get(pk=story_id)
        except Story.DoesNotExist:
            raise NotFound

        kwargs = {
            'story': story,
            'title': request.data.get('title'),
            'cover': request.data.get('cover'),
        }

        episode = Episode.objects.create(**kwargs)

        for image in dict(request.data.lists())['images']:
            EpisodeImage.objects.create(episode=episode, image=image)

        return Response({'episode_id': episode.id}, status=201)
```

Comment: Why you are not using `EpisodeSerializer`? You can do the validation there.

Comment: And what do you mean by "python cannot migrate validator depending on class"? If you add the `__eq__()` method and a `deconstruct()` method (of in most cases a `@deconstructible` decorator will work), it will be serialisable and thus can be migrated. See for example the [RegexValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/core/validators/#RegexValidator)

Comment: @dirkgroten if i add validator to field of model, and when i try to makemigrations, it brings error: There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files and refers to class validateimagesize

Comment: @Alex I have two models, where one of them refers to another and provides adding multiple images. To achieve that I had to override create without serializer

Comment: @DanabekDuisekov: If your validator is class, you need to make it serialisable, that's true. But that's quite easy to do, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#adding-a-deconstruct-method). If you can't figure it out, show the validator class and then we can help.

Comment: why not just call the corresponding function/validation method from your overwritten method, you have already overwrite it..

Comment: @Shakil i thought, but I can't, can u provide the code

Comment: @DanabekDuisekov can you please update your respective validationClass/method which you want to call, so that i can post an answer.

Comment: @DanabekDuisekov i have one more thing to know, what i can see that you want `batch-create` operation. If there is an error for one operation do you want to halt all other events or you just want that corresponding event not create ?

Comment: @Shakil updatet, if error need to stop all others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first we are going to validate all images is properly size/formatted or not and if there is no error then we will do create operation.

```py
from .validators import  ValidateImageSize

class EpisodeView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def create(self, request, story_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            story = Story.objects.get(pk=story_id)
        except Story.DoesNotExist:
            raise NotFound
        # now we will run image validation 
        custom_image_validator = ValidateImageSize() # with your desize size
        for image in dict(request.data.lists())['images']:
            custom_image_validator(image) # this will raise validation error if any validation error occur 

        # After that will do our regular work

        kwargs = {
            'story': story,
            'title': request.data.get('title'),
            'cover': request.data.get('cover'),
        }

        episode = Episode.objects.create(**kwargs)

        for image in dict(request.data.lists())['images']:
            EpisodeImage.objects.create(episode=episode, image=image)

        return Response({'episode_id': episode.id}, status=201)
```

Comment: @Danabek Duisekov please initialize custom_image_validator with your proper desire size at first.

Comment: it works for images, how can i also add validation for cover field here?

Comment: better is to use `EpisodeSerializer` to validate that.

Comment: one more question, it returns like keyarror ...., how to return validation error in json in this case

Comment: why not raise `serializers.ValidationError`